# Micro displacement not rendering with motion blur. (Blender 2.79 )

Tags: cycles-render-engine, armature, blur

Most of the bee is animated, specifically the wings, each flap is around 3 frames so there should motion blur happening at least with the wings.

I've attached the pertinent screen shots of settings as reference.

I've also tried rigging a primitive object with bones and animating it next to the bee with the same settings which does render with motion blur.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that rigged animation gets motion blur at the moment only over all object motion. Perhaps if the wings were separate objects? Also with such extreme blur, its better to fake it. That's what happens with helicopter blades and plane propellers. Maybe a volumetric shape would work and render quicker? Only issue would be lack of glint from surface of wings in a volume (no reflections)

Comment: I've tried it with another mesh it does render motion blur on deformations, just not on this mesh.

Comment: Attached a primitive example above, made in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

motion blur in blender is calculated based on the previous frame positions. so blender should load the scene for 2 frames to calculate motion blur, essentially to calculate motion. Adaptive subdivision is a heavy process and i believe happens only on the frame you are rendering so it has no data for the previous frame.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2.79, Cycles does not support adaptive (micro) subdivision and deformation blur on the same mesh. You should uncheck "adaptive" on the subdivision surface modifier if you need deformation blur.

See this documentation page from the main developer of this feature: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Maiself/Micropolygon_Displacement

Comment: A reference would make this answer much stronger...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change Shutter type to None. I'm not sure why, but from my experience, Top-Bottom doesn't give blur with motion based on rig bones movement (like flapping wings f.ex.).

Comment: Forgot I turned that on, was an attempt to get a result when None was producing none lol, still no go though

Comment: Weird. Why would one object produce blur and other not in the same circumstances? Are the origins of the armature and fly there or in center of the scene (0,0,0)?

Comment: I got it to go by turning adaptive subdivision off in the modifier stack, is that not supported?

Comment: You should probably answer your own question with your solution so that others can benefit, sometimes these replies are hidden from view.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely should place your solution here as an answer. It's pretty unusual problem, and knowing it surely will be useful for someone else too.